# F# Pass a list of triples through command line using Argu

Tags: f#, command-line-arguments, f#-argu

I have a list of triples, call them `(x : int, y : int, z : int)`, which I would like to pass to F# program. I use Argu (https://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/) to process command line parameters. It looks that Argu can handle a list of primitives, e.g. `list<int>`, but not `list<int * int * int>`.

Sure, it is possible to pass several lists of integers separately but it gets too ugly too fast and if the lists are even reasonably long, then it becomes unmanageable.

I wonder if it is possible to make Argu process list of tuples / triples without zipping several lists or rewriting a part of Argu code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Passing complex structured input like this through command line arguments feels like going against the grain. How about putting the tuples in a plain text file and providing the path instead?

Comment: @scrwtp Yeah, agree with you. I moved everything into the database => no parameters to pass at all. Sorry, I could not make less than that :)